# What's wrong with my solution for Max Counters codility challenge

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve the Max Counters codility problem [here](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/max_counters/start/). In this problem:

> You are given N counters, initially set to 0, and you have two possible operations on them:
>
> (i) increase(X) − counter X is increased by 1;
> (ii)max counter − all counters are set to the maximum value of any counter.
>
> A non-empty array A of M integers is given. This array represents consecutive operations:
>
> (i) if A[K] = X, such that 1 ≤ X ≤ N, then operation K is increase(X),
> (ii) if A[K] = N + 1 then operation K is max counter.
>
> The goal is to calculate the value of every counter after all operations.

Below is my solution:

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        int[] counters = new int[N];
        int maxVal = 0;
        int MAX_COUNTER = N+1;

        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++) {
            if(A[i] == MAX_COUNTER) {
                Arrays.fill(counters, maxVal);
            } else {
                counters[A[i]-1]++;
                maxVal = counters[A[i]-1];
            }
        }
        return counters;
    }
```

Codility report shows that the solution produce incorrect output for *small_random1* and *small_random2*.

Comment: Explain your code on this post instead of referencing to an external link, show what is expected to return, what is the current execution and what have you tried until now.

Comment: You should always put the actual problem statement or at least mention what you actually trying to solve in your post. The external link you shared is not showing the actual problem before login to that site.

Comment: Note: A good solution for this problem will take linear time.  Yours takes quadratic time.

Answer (score 1):

The way you were updating `maxVal` was wrong. For example, given integer N = 5 and array A such that:

```
A[0] = 3
A[1] = 4
A[2] = 4
A[3] = 1
```

If you run your code, the values of the `counters` and `maxVal` after each consecutive operation will be:

```
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0) maxVal = 1
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0) maxVal = 1
(0, 0, 1, 2, 0) maxVal = 2
(1, 0, 1, 2, 0) maxVal = 1
```

Clearly, after `A[3]` the `maxVal` will still be `2` and not `1`. Here I have fixed the issue by updating `maxVal` correctly:

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Math.max;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        int[] counters = new int[N];
        int maxVal = 0;
        int MAX_COUNTER = N+1;

        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++) {
            if(A[i] == MAX_COUNTER) {
                Arrays.fill(counters, maxVal);
            } else {
                counters[A[i]-1]++;
                maxVal = max(maxVal, counters[A[i]-1]);
            }
        }
        return counters;
    }
}
```

But, with this solution you will not able to pass this test as it will get `TIMEOUT ERROR` for large inputs. To pass this, you need to use an efficient data structure (e.g., segment-tree with lazy propagation during updates).